# creating a digital filter in android

Tags: android, signal-processing, lowpass-filter, transfer-function

I'm trying to deal with ECG signal processing in android. I want to implement simple digital filters (lowpass, highpass)

I've got a transfer function:

[image: click to see transfer function]

**here is what i've found:**

[wikipedia - lowpass filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter) - it looks quite easy here.

```
for i from 1 to n
  y[i] := y[i-1] + α * (x[i] - y[i-1])
```

but there is nothing about transfer function which I want to use.

I also found the following matlab code

```
%% Low Pass Filter  H(z) = (1 - 2z^(-6) + z^(-12)) / (1 - 2z^(-1) + z^(-2))
b = [1 0 0 0 0 0 -2 0 0 0 0 0 1];
a = [1 -2 1];
h_l = filter(b,a,[1 zeros(1,12)]); 
ecg_l = conv (ecg ,h_l);
```

but there is no function like `filter` and `conv` in java (or I missed something).

Also I was looking on stackoverflow for an answer. But I didn't found anything about transfer function.

so can someone help me? I just want to move on with my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a time-domain recurrence equation (such as the one you quoted from wikipedia), the corresponding transfer function in the z-domain can relatively easily be obtained by using the following properties:

[image: $$\begin{align} \mathcal Z\left{x[n-k]\right} &= z^{-k} X(z) \tag{1}\ H(z) &= \frac{Y(z)}{X(z)} \tag{2}\end{align}$$]

Where `X(z)` and `Y(z)` are the z-transforms of the time-domain input sequence `x` and output sequence `y` respectively.
Going the other way around, given a transfer function which can be expressed as a ratio of polynomials in z, such as:

[image: H(z) = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^N b_i z^{-i}}{1 + \sum_{i=1}^M a_i z^{-i}}]

the recurrence equation of the transfer function can be written as:

[image: y[n] = -\sum_{i=1}^M a_i y[n-i] + \sum_{i=0}^N b_i x[n-i]]

There are of course many different ways to implement such a recurrence equation, but a simple filter implementation following the [Direct Form II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_filter#Direct_Form_II) would be along the line of:

```
// Implementation of an Infinite Impulse Response (IIR) filter
// with recurrence equation:
//   y[n] = -\sum_{i=1}^M a_i y[n-i] + \sum_{i=0}^N b_i x[n-i]
public class IIRFilter {

  public IIRFilter(float a_[], float b_[]) {
    // initialize memory elements
    int N = Math.max(a_.length, b_.length);
    memory = new float[N-1];
    for (int i = 0; i < memory.length; i++) {
      memory[i] = 0.0f;
    }
    // copy filter coefficients
    a = new float[N];
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < a_.length; i++) {
      a[i] = a_[i];
    }
    for (; i < N; i++) {
      a[i] = 0.0f;
    }
    b = new float[N];
    i = 0;
    for (; i < b_.length; i++) {
      b[i] = b_[i];
    }
    for (; i < N; i++) {
      b[i] = 0.0f;
    }
  }

  // Filter samples from input buffer, and store result in output buffer.
  // Implementation based on Direct Form II.
  // Works similar to matlab's "output = filter(b,a,input)" command
  public void process(float input[], float output[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      float in  = input[i];
      float out = 0.0f;
      for (int j = memory.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
        in  -= a[j+1] * memory[j];
        out += b[j+1] * memory[j];
      }
      out += b[0] * in;
      output[i] = out;
      // shift memory
      for (int j = memory.length-1; j > 0; j--) {
        memory[j] = memory[j - 1];
      }
      memory[0] = in;
    }
  }

  private float[] a;
  private float[] b;
  private float[] memory;
}
```

which you could use to implement your specific transfer function like so:

```
float   g = 1.0f/32.0f; // overall filter gain
float[] a = {1, -2, 1};
float[] b = {g, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2*g, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, g};
IIRFilter filter = new IIRFilter(a, b);

filter.process(input, output);
```

Note that you can alternatively also factorize the numerator and denominator into 2<sup>nd</sup> order polynomials and obtain a cascade of 2<sup>nd</sup> order filters (known as [biquad filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_biquad_filter)).

Comment: thank you :) but in loop for(int j=memory.length-1;j>=0;j--) I see a mistake. 

cuz if memory.length=N
and indexes of tab are [0...N-1]
then if u call a tab like tab[N-1+1] then it will cause error

Comment: Yes, I forgot to incorporate an adjustment to the `memory` allocation to be of length `N-1`. Thanks.